# восстановление postgresql из pg_basebackup и архива wal

Tags: linux, postgresql, резервное-копирование, восстановление

Не получается стартануть базу.

Вот такой получился лог при попытки запуска архивной версии:

```
 Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main...
 The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
 2018-03-12 11:22:36.633 MSK [7789] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  работа системы БД была прервана; последний момент работы: 2018-03-07 06:00:04 MSK
 2018-03-12 11:22:37.022 MSK [7790] [н/д]@[н/д] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  неполный стартовый пакет
 2018-03-12 11:22:37.536 MSK [7793] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:38.049 MSK [7796] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:38.565 MSK [7799] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:39.080 MSK [7802] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:39.595 MSK [7805] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:40.106 MSK [7808] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:40.625 MSK [7812] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:41.136 MSK [7815] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:41.651 MSK [7818] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.163 MSK [7821] postgres@postgres ВАЖНО:  система баз данных запускается
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.172 MSK [7789] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  неверная запись контрольной точки
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.172 MSK [7789] ВАЖНО:  не удалось считать нужную запись контрольной точки
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.172 MSK [7789] ПОДСКАЗКА:  Если вы не восстанавливаете БД из резервной копии, попробуйте удалить файл "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label".
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.174 MSK [7788] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  стартовый процесс (PID 7789) завершился с кодом выхода 1
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.174 MSK [7788] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  прерывание запуска из-за ошибки в стартовом процессе
 2018-03-12 11:22:42.176 MSK [7788] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  система БД выключена
 postgresql@9.6-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main.
 postgresql@9.6-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
 postgresql@9.6-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Вот тут есть ссылка на wal, которого нет в бакупе (или они переименовываются?)

```
root@zaschita-zal-p:~# cat /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label
START WAL LOCATION: 7D/3C000028 (file 000000010000007D0000003C)
CHECKPOINT LOCATION: 7D/3C0040D0
BACKUP METHOD: streamed
BACKUP FROM: master
START TIME: 2018-03-07 06:00:05 MSK
LABEL: pg_basebackup base backup
root@zaschita-zal-p:~#
```

Есть такой в архиве. Но не подтянулся с `restore_command` в `recovery.conf`.

Comment: Ну раз уж дух поднял вопрос - в recovery.conf что было на момент старта?

Comment: я туда добавлял команду на то чтоб забирало валы с архива, но команду эту пг даже не пытался запускать

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, картина однозначно ясна по приведённому логу и исходникам базы. [Есть всего одно место](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c#L6217), откуда можно получить сообщения

> 2018-03-12 11:22:42.172 MSK [7789] ВАЖНО:  не удалось считать нужную запись контрольной точки
>   2018-03-12 11:22:42.172 MSK [7789] ПОДСКАЗКА:  Если вы не восстанавливаете БД из резервной копии, попробуйте удалить файл "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label".

[И чуть-чуть выше](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c#L6131) этого места есть код, который отметит в логе сообщением уровня `LOG` (`СООБЩЕНИЕ`) режим восстановления всегда, если база прочитала `recovery.conf` файл.

У вас ни одного из этих сообщений в логе нет. Единственное возможное объяснение - у вас нет `recovery.conf` файла. Это единственная возможность покинуть вызов функции `readRecoveryCommandFile` без получения `FATAL` ошибки и без установки переменной `ArchiveRecoveryRequested`.

А поскольку `recovery.conf` не было при старте `startup` процесса - то не имеет ровно никакого значения, что вы могли хотеть указать в `restore_command` поскольку это не было прочитано.

`recovery.conf` должен быть строго в корне PGDATA директории, на том же уровне, где лежат остальные `PG_VERSION`, `pg_xlog`, `pg_clog`, `postgresql.auto.conf` и другие части базы.

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ, но временное решение:

Изменил команду на

```
pg_basebackup -x --write-recovery-conf --format=t -z --pgdata=$BACKPATH$($DATE)/pg_basebackup/
```

Теперь база в полном комплекте архивируется и стартует.

Правильней было б научить ПГ тянуть валы из архива самому.